# What's the product rule for the exponential differential operator?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, differential-operators

So I was thinking say you have a linear differential operator such as the exponential differential one which is renown in some fields in physics:
$$e^{\mathrm D_x}\equiv\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\mathrm D_x^n}{n!},\text{ where } \mathrm D_x^n\equiv\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n},$$
and you applied it to a product of functions $u(x)\cdot v(x)$.

Then what would the "product rule" be for this operator? I.e.,
$$e^{\mathrm D_x}[u\cdot v]=?$$

---

**APPROACH:**
Is this it?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}(u\cdot v)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}u^{(n-i)}v^{(i)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{u^{(n-i)}}{(n-i)!}\frac{v^{(i)}}{i!}\overset{j=n-i}{=}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{u^{(j)}}{j!}\frac{v^{(i)}}{i!}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: Leibnitz formula and Cauchy product of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You can go on by introducing an auxiliary variable $t$ in order to make the respective Taylor series of $u$ and $v$ appear, as it follows :
$$
\begin{align}
e^{D_x}(uv)(x) 
   &= \sum_{i,j\ge0} \frac{u^{(i)}(x)}{i!}\frac{v^{(j)}(x)}{j!} \\
   &= \left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{u^{(i)}(x)}{i!}t^i \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{v^{(j)}(x)}{j!}t^j\right]_{t=1} \\
   &= \left[u(x+t)v(x+t)\right]_{t=1} \\
   &= u(x+1)v(x+1)
\end{align}
$$
This result is not surprising, since the operator $e^{D_x}$ is nothing else than the translation operator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $u(x+t)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty\dfrac{u^{(i)}(x)}{i!}(t-x)^i$?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.  No, it wouldn't. In fact, the series don't correspond to the expansion of $u(t)$ around $t = x$, as you suggest, but $u(x+t)$ around $t = 0$.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF.   You're welcome ;)